# Flyway: include external script

Tags: sql, database, flyway

There is maven flyway configuration that point to a general folder with all the migration scripts. Scripts have common patter like "V1.2.3.4__description". Also there are other .sql scripts in the same migrations folder that have arbityraty names. Is it possible to call/include external scripts (in the same folder) from inside regular flyway migration scripts?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to call external SQL scripts from your migrations, but  you could maybe insert the external SQL into your migrations using placeholders. These allow you to insert configurable values using `${ ... }`.

E.g. your migration scripts could look like:

```
SOME SQL...

${external_sql}

SOME MORE SQL...
```

Then, you could configure the external SQL in `flyway.conf`:

```
flyway.placeholders.external_sql=SOME EXTERNAL SQL...;
```

Or, if the external SQL needs to be loaded from files, you could configure the placeholder in the command line and set it's value to the contents of the external `.sql` file. E.g. something like:

`./flyway migrate "-placeholders.external_sql=$(cat ./sql/some_external_sql.sql)"`